# zurb foundation - change grid-container size?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

What is the default width of [.grid-container](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) on large screen? How can I change it and make it bigger? What is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quicker solution without messing up with the settings:

```
/**
* Change container size on xxlarge screen.
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 90em) {
    .grid-container {
        max-width: 85rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The default width of .grid-container is defined in _settings.css file. Check it in the Xy Grid section:

// 56. Xy Grid

$grid-container: $global-width;

So, the default width is $global-width. Then you can change it in the Global section:

// 1. Global

$global-width: rem-calc(1200);

For example: 1440px :

$global-width: rem-calc(1440);

Answer (score 1):

Simply open your "**_settings.scss**" file, run down to Section 2 "**Breakpoints**" (line 103) and edit the pixel values there as you prefer.

```css
// 2. Breakpoints
// --------------

$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
```